# Failed building wheel for gfootball

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error while installing Google research football.

Failed building wheel for gfootball

running build_ext
'gfootball' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Google Research Football compilation failed
Failed building wheel for gfootball
Running setup.py clean for gfootball
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for baselines ... done
Stored in directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-2bdp8pkh\wheels\47\4b\a3\0a25aebc24e2f3302802b56aef9855b3bc7bb051cc5bc3debd
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for wrapt ... done
Stored in directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d7\de\2e\efa132238792efb6459a96e85916ef8597fcb3d2ae51590dfd
Successfully built baselines wrapt
Failed to build gfootball
tensorflow 1.12.0 has requirement tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0, but you'll have tensorboard 1.14.0 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the error message that your `tensorboard` version is incompatible. You'll need to downgrade the module by running

```
pip install -I tensorboard==1.13.0
```